# How can I force Terminal.app to take up exactly half of my screen?

Tags: terminal, window-manager

I'm using Spectacle for Window Management and I regularly use the commands to split my screen horizontally for exactly two windows. It works quite well for most things, but not for applications like Terminal.app or Emacs, which size themselves down just a little bit so that the window size goes together with their monospaced text view. I see Spectacle resizing them to exactly half of the screen, and then the windows resizing just a tad right after.

Emacs on the left, Terminal.app on the right:

[image: Emacs on the left, Terminal.app on the right]

Is there any way to force these windows to stay the size that Spectacle is trying to set?

This seems like a non-issue, but it quickly becomes one when I have a more colorful desktop background. It's then quite distracting to have e.g. bright orange pixels all around those windows.

Comment: Can You try BetterTouchTool (www.bettertouchtool.net)? There's also window manager and it works great with my Terminal windows (exactly half of the screen).

Comment: That's only marginally better. The window aligns with the top left corner now, but on the bottom and the right, there's still space where I can see my desktop background. Still not exactly half of my screen :/

Comment: I use Moom for window management and really like it, but even it leaves a little space between Terminal windows when one is taking the left half and another is on the right half. But that gap is pretty small.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal windows can only be expanded based on the width/height of a single character in the font that is used. You might be able to experiment and find a size that is easy to read while allowing the window to resize perfectly.

Comment: That's exactly the annoying limitation I want to work around. Setting my font size to something else, maybe less readable, just so this (almost) doesn't happen, isn't anywhere close to that...